# target CleanPublish cannot find publish folder during Rebuild

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I've been having a build error where some .exe are not found in the folder `$(OutputPath)\app.publish`.

The problem occurs during execution of GenerateManifest target and happens roughly 50% of the time I do a rebuild.

My scenario is the following: I have a solution with several projects, which 2 or more are published via clickonce. Projects are built in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured out what was happening. My scenario is the following: I have a solution with several projects, which, at least 2, are published by clickonce and have to go through manifest generation during build.

The thing is, we have a unified output folder. So all projects are built to the same folder and the publish folder was the same for all projects: `$(OutputPath)\app.publish`.

The MSBuild target that creates the manifest for the clickonce looks for files in this folder . After doing its business, it deletes the folder.

Well, MSBuild builds (in my machine) 4 projects at a time, and the manifest generation of one project ended up deleting the publish folder the same time it was being used by the other publishable project.

I noticed there was a condition to the target (in the Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets file) that deletes the publish directory: `Condition="'$(PublishDir)'=='$(OutputPath)app.publish\' and Exists('$(PublishDir)')"`

So, I just set `$(PulishDir)` to `$(OutputPath)app.publish\$(AssemblyName)\`.

That way the folders weren't deleted. Well, even if they were, each project has it's own publish folder now.